# Execute eval() inside a specific div only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eval

I tried searching but i didnt find anything helpful :(

I have a draggable div where I can drag images/labels and text fields. To preview the contents of the div in a new div (dont ask me why lol), I created a function called "preview":

```
var myDraggableDiv = $('#div_draggable');

function preview()
{
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'div_preview';

$(div).html(myDraggableDiv.html()); // copy html
}
```

So, after executing the function, my preview div has the same contents of the draggable div. Now I need to execute a custom javascript inside the preview div. The custom javascript code is located inside a variable called "customJS". The updated function is:

```
function preview()
{
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'div_preview';

$(div).html(myDraggableDiv.html());
eval(customJS);
}
```

The main problem is that the custom javascript is executed globally, affecting also the draggable div. I need to execute this custom javascript, most likely using 'eval', only inside the elements of the preview div.

Suppose my custom script is:

```
var customJS = "$('img').hide();";
```

If I run eval(customJS), all the images inside both divs will hide.
Note I can have any valid javascript code in my customJS variable...

Can anybody help me? How can I limit the execution of my custom script to a specific element?

Thanks!

Comment: Come on now, [don't be eval](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval)

Comment: I don't think you can, unless you parse your js string and modify it before running. It would be better to use an iframe for preview, and no `eval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eval()` (it's the wrong tool for most jobs). In this case, a function will be much nicer:

```
var customJS = function(parent) {
    $('img', parent).hide();
};
```

Now, you can run `customJS(div)` and the selector will be relative to the `div` element.

By the way, take a look at [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/). It might be useful for you:

```
function preview() {
    var $clone = myDraggableDiv.clone();

    customJS($clone); // IMO, it would be nicer to
                      // just write your custom JS here.
}
```

Comment: Hm. Do you mean `$('img', parent).hide()`?

Comment: @VisioN: Yep, I do. Thanks for catching that.